# not found error in webmaster when redirection handled through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

I am trying to find answer for this for a long time.
I have created one site and i handle the not found page(404 pages) through .htaccess.
Everything works great but when i submitted to google webmaster for indexing (in fetch as google) it showing an error ( `status = not found`).
Does anyone know How to tell google to handle these pages (index these pages)

my .htaccess file is

```
ERRORDOCUMENT 404 /redirect.php
```

in my `redirect.php` file i take the necessary action.
like if URL is `www.mysite.com/username` then profile of that user is shown

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google will never index 404 error pages.

You can use `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /redirect.php [L]
```

which redirected all links to pages that do not exist

if you use:

```
RewriteRule ^ /redirect.php [R=301,L]
```

the link change in the browser. But with [L] you can show your page without link change.